# Can I set has a 2d array as key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I would like to use a 2d array as key set in JavaScript. Is it possible?

```
let set = new Set();
let myArr = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => new Array(2).fill(0));
set.add(myArr);
let myArr2 = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => new Array(2).fill(0));
set.add(myArr2); // It should not add a new element to the set because it's the same array
```

Comment: Arrays are objects in JavaScript, and objects are unique even if they contain the same values (e.g. `{} != {}`). If you change the fourth line to `let myArr2 = myArr` it works as you expect, because then they're both references to the same object. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do here? Maybe there's another way to accomplish it.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how a Set and object work. Your response was very helpful. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like Set keep unique objects values and an array, even if its elements are the same, the value of 2 arrays are always different. Correct?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Set`: whenever you do `new Array` (or similar), you create a *new* Array, whether or not it has the same values inside as another array. They occupy separate memory. For JavaScript two arrays are equal only when they really are the *same* single one array (not two that are alike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Set`: whenever you do `new Array` (or similar), you create a *new*, distinct Array, whether or not it has the same values inside as another array. These arrays occupy separate memory. For JavaScript two arrays are equal only when they really are the same *single* one array (not two that are alike).

If however you want different arrays to be considered the same when they have the same shape and same primitive values in them, then you can use a stringified version of them as key:

```js
let set = new Set();
let myArr = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => new Array(2).fill(0));
set.add(JSON.stringify(myArr));

let myArr2 = new Array(2).fill(0).map(() => new Array(2).fill(0));
set.add(JSON.stringify(myArr2));

console.log(...set);
```

Note that `JSON.stringify` is not a solution for *any* JavaScript object, but it will work as desired for arrays of arrays of ... of primitive values supported by JSON (strings, numbers, boolean, null).

Comment: Thank you. I got confused because if I have var i = 1; var j = 1; set.add(i); set.add(j); My set will only have one value

Comment: Yes, that is the difference between primitive values and objects. In JavaScript 1 is equal to 1, and "a" is equal to "a", but [1] is not equal to [1]. In JavaScript arrays are objects.